# How to access values from textbox in tablelayoutpanel in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, dynamic

I have created a screen for editing database records. After user selects the table, I have dynamically added Labels and TextBox inside the TableLayoutPanel1.  I want to know how to access the value present in the TextBox which is inside TableLayoutPanel1

I code which i used:

```
    Dim strSQL, strSQL1 As String
    Dim ln As Integer
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    connection = New OleDbConnection(CONNECT_STRING)
    connection.Open()
    ln = 0
    strSQL = " select * from syscat.columns where TABSCHEMA like 'QA1MM%' and TABNAME like 'SKU_STR_LIST' with ur  "
    RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + strSQL
    Dim selectCMD As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection)
    reader = selectCMD.ExecuteReader
    MessageBox.Show("Column: " & reader(0) & " ")
    While reader.Read()
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader(0)) Then

        Else
            TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 20
            Dim aLabel As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
            Dim aTextBox As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
            aLabel.Name = "New Label"
            aLabel.Text = reader(0).Text
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(aLabel, 0, ln)
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(aTextBox, 1, ln)
            ln = ln + 1
        End If
    End While
```

How can i access the value present in the aTextBox which i added dynamically inside the TableLayoutPanel1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you need to set a name on the TextBox. Basically aTextbox.Name = "TextBox1". Then you should be able to find the control by using:

```
Control c =  TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("TextBox1",true)
```

Keep in mind however that this will give you a control, not a textbox. So typecast it in whatever way you find suitable.

```
Ctype(c,TextBox)
DirectCast(c,TextBox)
```

Comment: If i give " Control c =  TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Find("TextBox1",true) " It is giving error 'Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Windows.Forms.Control' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Comment: Oh. Then you get an array of controls and not just 1. You will have to set the name dynamically. Like "Textbox"&ln to make sure all textboxes have unique names. Then extract the control from the array you get from find.

Answer (score 1):

As WozzeC says you need to give the text box a name that is unique, probably something like

```
 aTextBox.Name = "TextBox" & ln
```

Then you could find it this way

```
Dim words = TableLayoutPanel1.Controls("Textbox1").Text
```

or if its in the same loop

```
 Dim words = TableLayoutPanel1.Controls("Textbox" & ln).Text
```